# Tkinter Text widget. Unselect text

Tags: python, text, widget, tkinter

I have used a Text widget with `Tkinter` that copies selected text to the clipboard when a button is pressed. Now after the copy process I would like to unselect the text.
Any idea how that might work?

Since it seems to be necessary to post some code, for people to understand my problem in more detail, here it is:

```
def copy_to_clipboard(self, copy_string):
    #copy to clipboard function
    self.clipboard_clear()
    try:
        #text in outputlistfield marked, so copy that
        self.clipboard_append(self.outputlistfield.get("sel.first", "sel.last"))
    except:
        #no text marked
```

`outputlistfield` is a Text widget. If Text is selected, it shall be copied to clipboard. That works fine. But I would like to reset the selection, so that after the text is copied no text is selected anymore. So, any suggestions?

Comment: Don't know why people are always in a hurry to downvote...Give the guy a chance to explain,he just became a member today itself

Comment: @stevieG he's one interested user it seems as he just posts and gets the hell out hoping there would be a answer with all the code he needs next week when he logs back.

Comment: @KDawG:maybe he is new to stackoverflow,that's why & you just gave him 5-6 minutes

Comment: You are looking for `self.outputlistfield.tag_remove(SEL, "0.0", END)`. I do not know how to reopen your question so I can add that as an answer. However I have a few comments regarding your question: 1) Your problem is not related to clipboard copy so that pert should have been left out. 2) You have probably tried something what did not work for you. Would be great if you can show it. 3) Self contained and runnable minimal example which demonstrates the problem is the best way to get help.

Answer (score 5):

`self.outputlistfield.tag_remove(SEL, "1.0", END)` would do the trick. As in this example:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

class Main(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)  
        self.title("Test")

        self.text = Text(self)
        self.text.insert(END, "This is long long text, suitable for selection and copy.")
        self.text.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="Copy", command=self.OnCopy)
        self.button1.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

        self.button2 = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="Copy & Unselect", command=self.OnCopyDeselect)
        self.button2.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

    def OnCopy(self):
        try:
            text = self.text.selection_get()
        except TclError:
            print("Select something")
        else:
            self.clipboard_clear()
            self.clipboard_append(text)
        self.text.focus()

    def OnCopyDeselect(self):
        self.OnCopy()
        self.text.tag_remove(SEL, "1.0", END)

root = Main()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The correct text index is "1.0" -- lines start counting at one, not zero.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest minimal solution is to delete the "SEL" mark from the entire Text widget using {text widget}.tag_remove(Tkinter.SEL, '1.0', Tkinter.END) right after you have appended to the clipboard. Modified code (with one #NEW LINE, specific to your code) is as follows:

```
def copy_to_clipboard(self, copy_string):
    #copy to clipboard function
    self.clipboard_clear()
    try:
        #text in outputlistfield marked, so copy that
        self.clipboard_append(self.outputlistfield.get("sel.first", "sel.last"))
        self.outputlistfield.tag_remove("sel", "sel.first", "sel.last") #NEW LINE
    except:
        #no text marked
```

Comment: Also, please note that, as an option to try/except, you can check to see if any text is selected with the following `if self.outputlistfield.tag_ranges('sel'):`